# My Raspberry PI hangs after searching for files on the SD card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, raspbian-jessie, filesystem

Strange issue here: when performing simple file search under "/" or issuing du command on large folders, my RPi's OS dies and needs hard restart.
For example:
* find / -name "index.html"
* du -s /usr

It works for small folders but hangs for larger ones. The result is:

- all VNC & putty sessions disconnect with an error
- if there is alive putty session (if you're lucky) commands do not work:

[image]
[image]

I did apt-get update & upgrade but the situation is the same. 
The same happens if I plug the SD card to RPi 2 & RPi 3.

What could be the reason? Have you experienced something like that? And essentially how to solve it?

Details: 
Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
RPi 2 Model B, Revision a01041

**UPDATE:** It seems /var/log/syslog shows some hints:

```
Jul 13 19:37:21 pgeorgiev-rpi systemd[1]: Starting Session c4 of user pi.
Jul 13 19:37:21 pgeorgiev-rpi systemd[1]: Started Session c4 of user pi.
Jul 13 19:37:28 pgeorgiev-rpi systemd[1]: Got automount request for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc, triggered by 7938 (du)
Jul 13 19:37:28 pgeorgiev-rpi systemd[1]: Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
Jul 13 19:37:28 pgeorgiev-rpi systemd[1]: Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453286] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453309] [23c71a15] TCM> b913ad0c 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453318] [23c71a15] FDA> b913ac34 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453326] [23c71a15] DMA> 0 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453334] [23c71a17] TSK< b913ac34 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453342] [23c71a1b] TSK> b913ac34 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453350] [a3c71af6] PRD< b913ad0c 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453358] [a3c71af6] PRD1 b99b2d10 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453366] [a3c71af9] PRD2 1 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453374] [a3c71afc] PRD3 b3779b84 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453382] [a3c71afc] PDM> b913ad0c 0
Jul 13 19:37:54 pgeorgiev-rpi kernel: [18860.453390] [a3c71afd] REQ< b913ac34 10801
...
```

The full log is here: [syslog contents](http://pasted.co/d894f4d5)

Comment: You should look in `/var/log/syslog` at the time immediately before the reboot and see if any problem is indicated there (I am thinking of I/O failures).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a faulty SD card which sporadically stops working during intensive use. Try using a different one, and if the issue goes away, just dispose of the faulty card.

It might be that this faulty card will work in a different system (e.g. as a thumb drive in a card-reader, or in a cellphone / camera). For instance, it could be that this SD card is extremely sensitive to the supply voltage, and the PSU you use with the Pi is not that great. Though personally I would rather discard a potentially working SD card than store my data on a faulty one.